# Probability distribution from list of rasters using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have 100s (exactly 224) of wind distribution rasters.

I want to create a probability distribution raster of wind speed using all these rasters, so we can predict the possible wind speed in any location.

Is there any sufficient way in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: What does a "wind distribution raster" contain?  Speeds at each cell observed synchronously?  What, precisely, do you hope to store in your "probability distribution raster"? Also, how do you hope to use this for wind speed *prediction*? If you can articulate that, the nature of the solution will become evident.

Comment: Thank you whuber, the rasters contain wind speed for different time period, so each location can have different wind speed for  different time. I am trying to create one probability raster with probability of having wind speed greater than, let's say, 50 mph in each location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have what you need in just about the best possible form.  To estimate probabilities, use [GreaterThanFrequency](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Greater_Than_Frequency/009z0000007t000000/): at each cell in a group of overlapping rasters, it returns how many of those rasters have a value greater than a given value (such as 50).  Dividing this by the number of rasters (*e.g.*, 224) estimates the probability, *assuming the rasters are a representative set of data over time.*